# Solving equation $z^6 - 4z^2 - 2z + 8 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find solutions of $$z^6 - 4z^2 - 2z + 8 = 0$$
which are in the ring $P(0, 1, 2)$, where $P(z_0, r, R) := \{z \in C: r < |z - z_0| < R\}$

**My work so far**

I had two main ideas how it can be done. First one was to rewrite this in a nicer way:

$$z^2 (z^4 - 4) - 2z + 8 = 0$$

$$z^2(z^2-2)(z^2 + 2) + 4(2 - z) = 0$$

which didn't give me a lot of new information.

Second approach was just to brainlessly find $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5, z_6 \in C$ such that:
$$z^6 - 4z^2 - 2z + 8 = (z - z_0)(z - z_1)(z - z_2)(z- z_3)(z-z_4)(z - z_5)(z - z_6)$$

which is tedious to do but for sure will work. Is there any easier way how it can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by the ring $P(0, 1, 2)$? That's not standard notation

Comment: I mean that: $P(z_0, r, R) := \{z \in C: r < |z - z_0| < R\}$

Comment: Use Wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|\leqslant1$, then $|z^6-4z^2-2z|\leqslant7<8$, and therefore you don't have $z^6-4z^2-2z+8=0$. On the other hand, if $|z|=2$, then $|z^6|=64>|-4z^2-2z+8|$, and therefore, by Rouché's theorem, your polynomial has $6$ roots on $D(0,2)$. Since none of them belongs to $\overline{D(0,1)}$, they all belong to your annulus.

Comment: Hey Jose! Thank you very much for your answer! I have several questions related to it. How did you obtain that $|z^6| = 64 > |-4z^2 - 2z + 8|$? And could you please tell me in more detail the corollary that our polynomial has 6 roots on $D(0, 2)$? Also could you please explain what $D(x_0, y_0)$ means in your solution?

Comment: You can obtain $|-4z^2 - 2z + 8| < 64$ just by applications of the triangle inequality on each of the terms. So $|-4z^2 - 2z + 8| \leq 4|z|^2 + 2|z| + 8$. Then, assuming $|z| = 2$, the RHS of that inequality becomes 28 which is less than 64.  Rouche's Theorem is a pretty major result in complex analysis, and problems like this are classic examples of rouche's. You can find more about it in most complex analysis textbooks. Finally, $D(0,1)$ is (more) standard notation for the open disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1 \}$ More generally. $D(z_0, r) := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z - z_0| < r\}$.

Comment: If $|z|=2$, then $|-4z^2-2z+8|\leqslant4\times2^2+2\times2+8=28$. Rouché's theorem claims then that $z^6$ and $z^6-4z^2-2z+8$ have the same number of roots in $D(0,2)$. By the way,$$D(a,r)=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z-a|<r\}.$$

Comment: Perfect! I think I understand! Thank you very much